# C#/Unity Instantiating class creating copies with same instance ID of 0

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, instantiation

The function below is supposed to create a new instance of `SolarSystem_Manager` and add it to a list however when `var clone = Instantiate(_solar)` is run, it returns a `nullreference` error. All instances of `_solar` have the same ID when I created multiple and this was 0 and changing the variables of one also changes the variables of the others. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
private void createSolarSystem()
         {
             SolarSystem_Manager _solar = new SolarSystem_Manager();
             _solar.solarSystem = new SolarSystem(transform.GetComponent<Galaxy>(), Random.Range(9, 10), new List<LQPlanetManager>(), new SunManager());
             var clone = Instantiate(_solar);
             solarSystems.Add(clone);
         }
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your other classes.  Is solar system manager a UnityEngine.Object? Instantiate only works with UnityEngine.Object types. As far as changing a variable changes across all "copies", those copies must be using the same ref instance to store data.

Comment: If however `SolarSystem_Manager` is a `UnityEngine.Object` (I guess a `MonoBehaviour`) type you **may NOT** use `new` to create it! You should get a warning about it

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't instantiate a Unity object with the `new` keyword. You should rather make a prefab of SolarSystem_Manager inside the editor and store it inside some variable:

1. Add this to your class:

   `[SerializeField] private GameObject _solarSystemManagerPrefab;`
2. Inside the editor, create a prefab and drag and drop it into `_solarSystemManagerPrefab`.
3. Now you can instantiate your prefab like this:

   `GameObject clone = Instantiate(_solarSystemManagerPrefab)`